# how to make it possible to save it 1 times only in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
$ctr = 0;
foreach($_POST['field_name'] as $key => $field_name)
   foreach($_POST['field_name1'] as $key => $field_name1)
   {
{
   if($_POST['field_name'][$key]){
      if($_POST['field_name1'][$key]){
      $sqli = "INSERT INTO farmersform (IDTwo,IDThree,IDFour,FCrops,FLandArea) VALUES ('$IDTwo','$IDThree','$IDFour','$field_name','$field_name1')";
      $result = $conn->query($sqli);
      if($result){
         $ctr++;
      }
   }
}
```

}
}

this is my code and if it save it saves 2 similar data in the datable how can i fix this?

Comment: are field_name & field_name1 both arrays ?

Comment: yes ma'am both arrays

Comment: close the question properly

Answer (score 1):

Remove one of the `foreach` loops. Your code should still work with some adjustments assuming that `field_name` and `field_name1` both have the same array length.

```
$ctr = 0;
foreach($_POST['field_name1'] as $key => $field_name1) {
  if ($_POST['field_name'][$key]) {
    if ($_POST['field_name1'][$key]) {
      $sqli = "INSERT INTO farmersform (IDTwo,IDThree,IDFour,FCrops,FLandArea) VALUES ('$IDTwo','$IDThree','$IDFour','{$_POST['field_name'][$key]}','$field_name1')";
      $result = $conn->query($sqli);
      if ($result) {
        $ctr++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what if i had 3 array i had edit the code and not working now

Comment: As long as the array length is same for all arrays, the code will work. If you're trying to add more arrays, you'll have to reference it with `$_POST['yourThirdArray'][$key]`. Replacing "yourThirdArray" with your actual array name. This is what I did when referenced your `field_name` array with `{$_POST['field_name'][$key]}`

Comment: thanks again sir.. how about getting recent autoincrement in another table and post it here cos there should be an IDOne and the content of that is the IDOne in table_b can u ask for help.. sorry im newbie in this i just want to learn more.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. Since this new question isn't your original issue, I would recommend you start a new question.